# How to run enlightenment wayland in docker container?

Tags: docker, x11, wayland

I am trying to run enlightenment(https://www.enlightenment.org/start) in a docker container,previously enlightenment is based on X11,but the latest version of enlightenment support wayland. As I searched,we can use the -v parameter when use the "docker run" command to start a docker image like :

```
$ docker run -it \
--net host \ # may as well YOLO
--cpuset-cpus 0 \ # control the cpu
--memory 512mb \ # max memory it can use
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \ # mount the X11 socket
-e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY \ # pass the display
-v $HOME/Downloads:/root/Downloads \ # optional, but nice
-v $HOME/.config/google-chrome/:/data \ # if you want to save state
--device /dev/snd \ # so we have sound
--name chrome \
jess/chrome
```

(Reference: https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/docker-containers-on-the-desktop/)

But this is based on X11.Currently I do not use the X11,and use the wayland based enlightenment,How can I show my enlightenment UI in docker container?

Answer (score 1):

According to

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330366/how-can-i-run-a-graphical-application-in-a-container-under-wayland

you mount some device such as

`/run/user/1000/wayland-0`

in your

`docker run`

command

and here is an extract from

https://github.com/duzy/docker-wayland/blob/master/run.sh

`docker run \
    --name $container \
    -v "$(pwd):/home/user/work" \
    --device=/dev/dri/card0:/dev/dri/card0 \
    --device=/dev/dri/card1:/dev/dri/card1 \
    --device=/dev/dri/controlD64:/dev/dri/controlD64 \
    --device=/dev/dri/controlD65:/dev/dri/controlD65 \`